# WXFormBuiler Error loading library /home/.../wxFormBuilder/_install/lib/wxformbuilder/libforms

Tags: python, wxformbuilder

I install wxformbuilder with tutorial from github without error but when I start it mesage error above. Can everyone tell me how to fix this error. I install with these step:

> Pre-requisites for Ubuntu:
>
> *sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-dev meson*
>
> Build and run:
>
> *meson _build --prefix $PWD/_install*
>
> *ninja -C _build install*
>
> *./_install/bin/wxformbuilder*

Comment: Do you have as a result folder ./install/lib ? What does it contain? Which meson version are you using?

Comment: I reinstall this link and it worked.
https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder/tree/wx31